# Topological space (closed )

Tags: general-topology

Is every finite subset of topological space is closed?
 prove or disprove 
A finite subset can be open as well as closed 
I'm confused about it how to prove it .

Comment: It's false. It's true for every topological space which is Hausdorff

Comment: @Jakobian All finite subsets of a topological space $X$ are closed if and only if $X$ is T1, actually.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yeah, sorry, so far I didn't need to consider any topological space which isn't Hausdorff (they are main focus in Analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example the topological space $X = \lbrace \sigma, \eta \rbrace$, where the topology is $\tau = \lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \eta \rbrace, X \rbrace$. What can you say about the subsets now? Which ones are closed?

What happens if we put the discrete topology on $X$ (i.e. every subset is open)?